# Get information from multiple identical mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say i have 4 identical tables: table1, table2, table3, table4

All table have same structure:
id total date

I want to get all information from all tables using same condition. I mean merge 4 sql requests in 1

So instead of having these 4 sql, have just one. Remember, same condition for all tables, in our case date = 2011-06-23

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where date = '2011-06-23'
SELECT * FROM table2 where date = '2011-06-23'
SELECT * FROM table3 where date = '2011-06-23'
SELECT * FROM table4 where date = '2011-06-23'
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you tell us a bit about the actual use case?  From just the question itself it sounds like there might be some data architecture changes you might be able to make that would ultimately make your life easier than doing Union after Union after Union.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(SELECT * FROM table1 where date = '2011-06-23')
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table2 where date = '2011-06-23')
UNION    
(SELECT * FROM table3 where date = '2011-06-23')
UNION    
(SELECT * FROM table4 where date = '2011-06-23')
```

[UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) is what you are looking for